# ColumnHeaderStyle Not Working While adding it to DataGridStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a new DataGridStyle as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
            <Style
                x:Key="DGR"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}"
                TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
            </Style>
            <Style
                x:Key="DGC"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}"
                TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
            </Style>
            <Style
                x:Key="DataGridStyle"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}"
                TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{DynamicResource DGC}" />
                <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{DynamicResource DGR}" />

            </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

My DataGrid is just like this:

```
<DataGrid Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle}"/>
```

But because of some reason only the `DataGridRow` style is working, the `columnHeaderStyle` style seems to be ignored.

If I set the `ColumnHeaderStyle` explicitly it works:

```
<DataGrid Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle}" ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource DGC}"/>
```

Here's an use example of [DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.columnheaderstyle?view=netcore-3.1) from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your Column Header style in your Datagrid's style resource like below, it should work then.

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}"
       TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="RowStyle" Value="{DynamicResource DGR}" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks! This Works Great! But I'm looking forward to use it the Microsoft way (I added the microsoft's example to my question).

Comment: Isn't this redundant, since  `DGC` style is already having `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />` ?

Comment: @AndreGamez I can't figure out why the header style is not working as a resource, maybe something is overriding it.

Comment: @Cfun no actually the `DGC` style isn't working here. So. the redundant one is `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />`

Comment: I'm using Material Design, that could be a possibility?

Comment: Yes that's the reason I guess, cause previously I tested it in a project which is also using `Material Design toolkit` and it caused the same problem as yours, but in a new clean project, Microsoft's example is working fine.

Comment: I know it is not working but why you kept this line then? `<Setter Property="ColumnHeaderStyle" Value="{DynamicResource DGC}" />`?

Comment: @Cfun I just forgot to remove it :) sorry my bad